# В чём причина ошибки TabError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в `Python` и делаю программу для работы с файлом:

```
def show ():
    with open('adressbook.txt', 'r') as file:
        while True:
            listline = file.readline()
            if len(listline) == 0:
                    break
            print(listline)
```

Почему мне выдаёт ошибку, если я перед `break` стираю один знак табуляции?

```
def show ():
    with open('adressbook.txt', 'r') as file:
        while True:
            listline = file.readline()
            if len(listline) == 0:
                break
            print(listline)
```

***Ошибка:***

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: Какую ошибку? Приведите её, пожалуйста, в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Вы не могли случайно смешать табуляцию и пробелы, получив `TabError`?

Comment: Потому что вы смешали в коде табы и пробелы, используйте что-то одно

Comment: я не смешивал вроде0_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы смешали табуляцию и пробелы. Используйте что-то одно.

PEP 8 (руководство по стилю кода) [рекомендует](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) использовать 4 пробела.